# How does Tensorflow MobileNetV1 SSD Coco implementation work

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, object-detection

I'm trying to convert the Tensorflow [ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz) model to a PyTorch model in an efficient way, so I got all the tensorflow layers and I mapped them into the layers of a predefined MobileNetV1_SSD class.

The class was taken from https://github.com/qfgaohao/pytorch-ssd and was referred to the standard MobileNetV1 SSD architecture defined in the official paper. The problem is that when I mapped the layers from TF to PyTorch I got some layer dimension mismatches like if there were some changes from the initial architecture. 
Adapting the class in according to the downloaded model I got this:

```
extras = ModuleList([
    Sequential(
        Conv2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=256, kernel_size=1),
        ReLU(),
        Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        ReLU()
    ),
    Sequential(
        Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=128,kernel_size=1),
        ReLU(),
        Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        ReLU()
    ),
    Sequential(
        Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=1),
        ReLU(),
        Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        ReLU()
    ),
    Sequential(
        Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1),
        ReLU(),
        Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        ReLU()
    )
])

regression_headers = ModuleList([
    Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=3 * 4, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=6 * 4, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=6 * 4, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=6 * 4, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=6 * 4, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=6 * 4, kernel_size=1, padding=1), 
])

classification_headers = ModuleList([
    Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=3 * num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=6 * num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=6 * num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=6 * num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=6 * num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
    Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=6 * num_classes, kernel_size=1, padding=1),
])
```

**OK**: The translation between models give me no errors

**FAIL**: I just have a problem when I have to evaluate the PyTorch model because kernel sizes and some in_channels and out_channels in the extras/classification/regression do not match the initial architecture specifications

> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2781) must match the size of tensor b (3000) at non-singleton dimension 1

**QUESTION**
Does somebody knows something about how Tensorflow developers implemented this model? So how did they manage the reduction of output in the first layer (from 6 * num_classes to 3 * num_classes) when choosing the anchors?